# How to make fixed columns dynamic using react-virtualized library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

Using this library https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/MultiGrid

I created multiGrid like this:

```
<MultiGrid
  cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
  columnCount={tableHeaders.length}
  columnWidth={cache.columnWidth}
  deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
  height={height}
  rowCount={data.length}
  rowHeight={40}
  width={width}
  fixedRowCount={1}
  enableFixedColumnScroll
  enableFixedRowScroll
  hideBottomLeftGridScrollbar={true}
  hideTopRightGridScrollbar={true}
/>
```

if add `fixedCoulmnCount = {1}` it freezes the 1st column, that's awesome but I need to send that number using function so that I can send dynamic column numbers to freeze. 
sometimes I need to freeze 1st two columns, sometimes need to freeze 1st three columns 
I tried calling the function as below:

```
fixedColumnCount = {getFreezeColNo} //this is prop in multigrid to freeze coulmns

function getFreezeColNo() {
    return 1;
  }
```

and I tried the arrow function also like:

```
fixedColumnCount={() => {
                return 1;
              }}
```

but I got this error for the above code:

[image] 
can anyone give a solution for this, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixedColumnCount expects a number not a function, but you've provided a function to it, therefore you are receiving NaN. Give it a try by actually calling that getFreezeColNo function.

```
  fixedColumnCount = {getFreezeColNo()}
```